# Need a monthly date picker library for angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using this (https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker) library for datepicker but I want to change format from day selection to month, any solution ?

Comment: What's wrong with dropdown?

Comment: Month and year selection is not available.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

It has many options to customize it.

Comment: Month and year selection is not available.. :(